# Adding tab item works from form, doesn't work from UserControl on form

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying tabs.

I have a MainWindowView.xaml as following:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:WorkspaceViewModel}">
            <view:StartView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="N" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{Binding DictionaryButton}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

And an UserControl StartView

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding DictionaryButton}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Which should be inside first default tab item on load:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
         Workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();
         Workspaces.Add(new WorkspaceViewModel { Header = "Start"});
    }
```

DictionaryButton is a RelayCommand in MainWindowViewModel.

```
public RelayCommand DictionaryButton
{
    get { return dictionaryButton ?? (dictionaryButton = new RelayCommand(() => ShowDictionaries())); }
}
private void ShowDictionaries()
{
     Workspaces.Add(new WorkspaceViewModel { Header = "New workspace"});
}
```

This should add new tab item to tab control. But it doesn't.

In debugger I see, how items are adding to Workspaces on button click, but there is no actual new tab item showing.

I added keybinding to MainWindowView to the same command, and it's working as expected. If I add button to MainWindowView and direct it to DictionaryButton - it's also working.

But it doesn't work from UserControl StartView. Could you please show me why?

Comment: What kind of collection is Workspaces? If it doesn't inherit from INotifyCollectionChanged changing items in it won't affect the view. Try changing it to ObservableCollection<T> and see if it works.

Comment: public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces { get; set; }

Comment: Aha, WorkspaceViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged, but no INotifyCollectionChanged. I'll try and revert

Comment: Or I shouldn't? :)

Comment: No need to add the  INotifyCollectionCha‌​nged in the WorkspaceViewModel. It's just for the collection that contains the items, but since you are using ObservableCollection‌ you are ok. I added an answer with an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the UserControl is instead the MainWindow but the tabs are binded in the MainWindow. If that is so what I see you have different instances of the MainWindowViewModel.

This creates one instance of the MainWindowViewModel in the MainWindow.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

And this creates another in the UserContol.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

So adding new tab in the ViewModel in the user control won't add it in the MainWindow which actually binds the tabs.

Comment: Yes, I checked and found that there were two independent Workspaces on usercontrol click and keybinding press. Could you point me to right direction to resolve this issue?

Comment: DataContext is propagated through the LogicalTree. So it should be sufficient if you just remove the code that sets the UserControl DataContext.